Why is my footer not visible in Sharepoint 2019 custom form
My share point 2013 on premises branding contains a footer. The footer is visible on-site pages but not on any custom list forms. why is this so?
However, this is not a problem on my subsites as the footer automatically appears on all site pages and custom form.
Why am I only facing a problem on my custom-form in main site?

My form was linked to a different master page. To resolve this, I found where the master page was linked in the form .aspx file and changed the master page link to the correct one and that resolved my issue.
